# How to assign a higher level on a uiview in order to make it override another view?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a uiview and added a sub-uiview on it. Then I allow user to drag the sub-view around the screen freely. But I have problem when moving the sub-view on top of the screen. Please see below picture. The sub view override the top uiview on the screen. What I want is to let the top uiview to override the sub-view. How can I change the level of a uiview in this case?

[image]

when I use `self.titleView.bringSubviewToFront(sv)`

I see another problem as shown in below image. The status bar is not at the top of the image view.

[image]

Comment: What is a superview of the draggable view?

Comment: the superview of the draggable view is the image view

Comment: I've update my answer

Comment: is your status bar added programmatically or via info.plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bringSubviewToFront`on parent view to bring sub view to front as follow:

objective-C:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

swift:

```
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)
```

Edit:

use below method to manage views:

```
bringSubviewToFront(_:)
sendSubviewToBack(_:)
removeFromSuperview()
insertSubview(_:atIndex:)
insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)
insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)
exchangeSubviewAtIndex(_:withSubviewAtIndex:)
```

like,

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(myView)
```

For more detail check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW46

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it works partly. I updated the post. How to bring the status bar to front?

Answer (score 1):

```
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(view)
```

**UPDATE**

Pay attention: you must considered that parentView is the parent of your view. To explain better this concept if you have a line like this:

```
self.container.addSubview(view)
```

so `self.container` is the view parent's, dont confuse it with the view below your view...it may not be the same.

Comment: Please check the second screenshot. It doesn't work for the container but doesn't work for the status bar. How to let status bar override my sub-view?

Comment: Depend by where you add your container. If you container was adding to UIWindow so you view are be able to stay above status bar. Are you using a custom third part library ?

Answer (score 0):

If your draggable view is a subview of the image view try to set [masksToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/masksToBounds) to true:

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = True
```

But the reason of your issue is probably because you set [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/zPosition) of `draggableView.layer` to some positive number. Usually it is better to use methods such as [insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:aboveSubview:) and [bringSubview(toFront:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:) to manage subview's order.

Comment: the second screenshot shows that the problem is the status bar on top of the screen. Is there a way to configure its layer?